# Random Images in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

looking to make an app that will randomly generate images in xcode. Using the following code to generate the images into a UIImageView:

```
- (IBAction)pushGenerateImage {
    NSArray *myImageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", @"image4.jpg", nil];
    int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count]; 

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]];
    GeneratedImage.image = myImage;
}
```

This all works fine for generating the images, however the uiimageview will occasionally turn blank. If anyone knows how to stop this i'd be grateful, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are looping through an array with an empty index, or one of your pictures is blank. Check and make sure that your array is working properly. Try subtracting 1 from image's count, and see if it displays all the pictures and works fine

```
- (IBAction)pushGenerateImage {
    NSArray *myImageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", @"image4.jpg", nil];
    int index = arc4random() % [(myImageNames count - 1)]; 

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]];
    GeneratedImage.image = myImage;
}
```

Look at the 3rd line. I'm not sure if this is proper syntax, but it may work

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch for your feedback. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by subract 1 from images count though? Sorry if it seems stupid, I'm a bit of a noob to xcode and objective c though.

Comment: I tried it and didn't have any luck. Thanks a lot for trying though, anyone else got any ideas?

Comment: When i say it didn't i mean the 'count - 1' solution didn't work, i'm not sure if there's any other way to subtract 1 from the image's count however.